# How to replace a letter in a sea of recurring letter with php?

Tags: php

```
$aEnd = "123/123/432/Omeagle";

$aEnd = str_replace("/", "-", $aEnd); // Output: "123-123-432-Omeagle"
$finda = strpos($aEnd, "-");
$countHypen = 0;
$wordLength = 0;
foreach($aEnd as $word){
    $wordLength += 1;
    if($word == "-"){
        $countHypen +=1;
        if($countHypen == $finda){
            break;
        }       
    }
    $aEnd = substr_replace($aEnd," ",$wordLength, 1);    
}
```

**Problem**

As you can see from the code above, I am trying to replace the fourth occurrence of the word but the way I did it is super duper inefficient as I have to run this portion quite a lot of times plus the length of the `$aEnd` is always changing.

**Question**

Is there any better way? Thanks.

**Expecting Output**

From: `123/123/432/Omeagle`

To: `123-123-432 Omeagle`

Comment: Unless your PHP version is too old - what about just `$aEnd = sprintf('%s-%s-%s %s', ...explode('/', $aEnd, 4));`? https://3v4l.org/dWCCu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace` should work here, using the following pattern:

```
\/(?=.*\/)
```

This will target any path separator which is *not* the final one, and then we replace it with dash.  After this, we make a single call to `str_replace` to replace the final remaining path separator with a space.

```
$aEnd = "123/123/432/Omeagle";
$output = preg_replace("/\/(?=.*\/)/", "-", $aEnd);
$output = str_replace("/", " ", $output);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
123-123-432 Omeagle
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But I'll only be able to mark this as the answer in 6 mins. Thanks so much btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can do all the replacements in one call to `preg_replace`, replacing `/` that are followed by another `/` (`/(?=.*/)`) with `-`, and a `/` not followed by `/` (`/(?=[^/]*$)`) with a space:

```
$aEnd = "123/123/432/Omeagle";
$aEnd = preg_replace(array('#/(?=.*/)#', '#/(?=[^/]*$)#'), array('-', ' '), $aEnd);
echo $aEnd;
```

Output:

```
123-123-432 Omeagle
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SGm0l)